# Write down all subgroups of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{12 \mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

We know that the subgroups of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$ are defined as;
Let $n$ be a positive integer.
Let $d$ be a positive divisor of $n$, say $n = kd$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Then $ \\{ \overline{0}, \overline{d}, \overline{2d} , ..., \overline{(k-1)d} \\} $ is a subgroup of
$\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$.

In my exercise I get that $12$ is divisible by $1,2,3,4, 6$ and $12$, this would result in $$\{\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \overline{2}, ..., \overline{11}\}$$ but by the property of divisibility does this not mean that for every $n$ we choose for $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$, that the subgroup is always $\\{\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \overline{2}, ..., \overline{n-1}\\}$, since every n is divisible by $1$?

Comment: The order of a subgroup should divide the order of the group, so you should be looking for subgroups of orders $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12$.

Comment: $\{\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \overline{2}, ..., \overline{11}\}$ is $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and it is a (non-proper) subgroup of itself; another subgroup is, for example, $\{\overline{0}, \overline{3}, \overline{6}, \overline{9}\}$

Comment: Yes, by the most common understanding, every group is a subgroup of itself. But there are other subgroups, e.g. always the trivial one.  Or 0,6. Or 0,2,4,6,8,10. Or 0,3,6,9.

Comment: Look for subsets that are closed under group operation.

Comment: Yes, that will always be *one* subgroup (and it is always the *same* thing as $\frac {\mathbb Z}{n\mathbb Z}$ but not the only subgroup.  Also note id $d = n$ then $\{\overline n\} = \{\overline 0\}$ was also always be a subgroup.  But those aren't the only ones.  (Unless $n$ is prime... then those *are* the only two subgroups).

Comment: Furthermore, every subgroup is cyclic, and so the divisors of 12 are in bijection with the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, all the subgroups of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{12 \mathbb{Z}}$ are $\{ \overline{0}\}$, $\{ \overline{0}, \overline{1}, ..., \overline{11}\}$, $\{ \overline{0}, \overline{2}, ..., \overline{10}\}$, $\{ \overline{0}, \overline{3}, ..., \overline{9}\}$, $\{ \overline{0}, \overline{4}, ..., \overline{8}\}$ and $\{ \overline{0}, \overline{6}\}$? And in the case of a prime $n$ all the subgroups would be $\{ \overline{0}\}$ and$\{ \overline{0}, \overline{1}, ..., \overline{n-1}\}$?

Comment: Yes correct (in the last but one subgroup listed, the dots can be saved).